# Why do both of the width and height of UISearchDisplayController's searchResultsTableView become twice after clicking the tabBar？

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I use a `tabbarController` to manage two controllers (one is used for searching). After the search is finished, I could get the right `tableViewCells`. Then, I keep the searched results, clicking the tabBar to go to the other controller.

However, when I come back to the `searchResultsTableView`, I get the cell with twice of its old width(640 pixs now). Why?

And the `searchResultsTableView`'s width and height both become twice, too.

Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: can u show us the how are u seting the height of cell ?

Comment: I set the height of cell using :
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0;
}`